# $\mathbb R - \mathbb R$ notation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, notation

In multi-variable calculus I find this notation $\mathbb R - \mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^m - \mathbb R^n$ the course material assumes that I am familiar with this notation.

As an example "We usually denote $\mathbb R^n- \mathbb R$ by means of ordinary lower case or capital letters."

What I want to know is how this $\mathbb R^n- \mathbb R$ is read?

Comment: What it denotes is functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, I suppose.

Comment: Can we get some context in which this notation is used? It looks a little ambiguous to me.

Comment: If you mean function signatures like $f : \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, please edit your question to make it clear for readers. The arrow is \rightarrow in the math markup.

Comment: $\mathbb R $- {o} is used when a function cannot contain a x value that is 0, hope this provides more context